VBA "does not equal" code not stepping through IF statement as expected
There are 2 separate data sources with a Status Code listed. One status code is an Autonumber and the other is a string (Access table and SQL table, respectively).
I'm looking to see if the Status fields from each record set match and if they don't, make updates.
    If rst!StatusCodeID <> CLng(DLookup("[StatusCodeID]", "ref_StatusCode", "[StatusCode] = '" & rstLocal!STATUS_CODE & "'")) Then
          rst.Edit
    End if

Each time the break hits the If statement it skips the edit even when the two record sets don't match. I set a debug.print to the immediate window and here are the results
ID, rst!StatusCodeID, rstLocatl!STATUS_CODE:
243011, 3, 3   
429564, 1, 0 
478870, 1, 0  
502598, 1, 0

ref_StatusCode Table:



StatusCodeID
STATUS_CODE
Desc




1
0
Inactive


2
1
Withdrawn


3
3
Active




Please provide the records within ref_StatusCode for StatusCode=3 and 0. I bet they are 3 and 1.

But are you sure that rst!StatusCodeID is a Long? In Immediate Window they look the same... Try `CLng(rst!StatusCodeID) <> CLng(DLookup("[StatusCodeID]",..' and see if this changes something.

@FaneDuru it did not make a difference by converting both to Long.

@BartMcEndree Table reference has been added.

It appears that the field name in the table is STATUS_CODE instead of StatusCode, and since the field is numeric, removing the single quotes is necessary. Using single quotes for numeric fields in SQL can lead to a "datatype mismatch" error, so it’s important to format the SQL query correctly depending on whether the field is numeric or text.
If rst!StatusCodeID <> CLng(DLookup("[StatusCodeID]", "ref_StatusCode", "[STATUS_CODE] = " & rstLocal!STATUS_CODE)) Then
    rst.Edit
End If

